# Login failed for user -> #c to database

Tags: c#, database, authentication

Hello guys im trying to connecty my textboxes into my database" loonberekening table werknemer"

But im getting an error named : Login failed for user

can someone help me?
Thanks

```
 private void btnOpslaanwerknemergegevens_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string database = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=E:\gip_stap_2\loonberekening.mdf;Integra‌​ted Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;InitialCatalog=loonberekening";
        string werknemergegevens = "insert into loonberekening.werknemer (naam,voornaam) values ('"+this.txtNaam.Text+"','"+this.txtVoornaam.Text+"');";
        SqlConnection cnnLoonberekening = new SqlConnection(
        @"Data Source=.; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\loonberekening.mdf;Initial Catalog=loonberekening");
        SqlCommand scmdLoon = new SqlCommand(werknemergegevens, cnnLoonberekening);
        SqlDataReader check;


        try{
            cnnLoonberekening.Open();
            check = scmdLoon.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Opgeslagen");
            while (check.Read())
            {
            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: DO you know what programming language you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask why you are not doing this 
SqlConnection cnnLoonberekening = new SqlConnection(
        database);

instead of setting the database variable to the connection string and then typing the whole thing out again? the database string variable has all the components you need. It has integrated security which uses your windows ID, otherwise you would need to add UID=[YourUserNameHere];PWD[YourPasswordHere] to the connection string.

Comment: How do i add an UID in sql? can you help me